# Cannot use an import statement outside of a module

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, import

I am trying to use the mathjs library to calculate complex solutions to the quadratic equation but I keep getting errors depending on the way I try to import the library into my code. I tried using this method:

I have this statement at the top of my root.js file:

```
import {sqrt} from '/node_modules/mathjs';
```

and this within my html code

```
<script src = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js type = "text/javascript"> </script>
<script src = 'rootcalc.js' type = "text/javascript" ></script>
```

When I load this in live server on chrome I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at rootcalc.js:1:1)" error. What is the proper way to use a javascript library when using npm to install it. I am relatively new to coding and still in school so any advice would be helpful.

Here is the entirety of the code:

[My JS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s70hh.png)
[My HTML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN26W.png)

Another way I tried to do this was by using type = "module" instead of type = "text/javascript" and then inside the JS file I did

```
const {sqrt} = require("mathjs")
```

but I get a require is not defined error.

Comment: `type="module"`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [mathsjs npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs) *"Math.js can be used in both node.js and in the browser."*.

That means if you want to use it on the front end you only need to have:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@11.8.2/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
```

Then at the bottom of your `<html>` before the closing `</body>` tag test it worked by using:

```
<script>
    console.log(math.sqrt(16));
</script>
```

Or if you are using it on the server a common practice is to specify `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`. This will allow you to use:

```
import {sqrt} from "mathjs";
console.log(sqrt(16));
```

inside your server-side code. However, if you do add `"type": "module"` into your `package.json` then you can't use the `require('name')` approach (there are workarounds to allow you to use both though).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. When I added ``` "type": "module" ``` into package.json and I changed my import statement to the one you have I now get a 
"cannot use import statement outside of module" error.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you run `npm install mathjs`? Also, did you restart your server after adding `"type": "module"` into your `package.json`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Additionally, I am getting an "expected comma" error in the package.json file on vscode whenever I add "type": "module".

Comment: You need a trailing comma after every `"key" : "value"` pair if you have another key after it in json. So do `"type": "module",` and that will get rid of the "expected comma" error.

Comment: Ah okay. That fixed the error but still getting the "cannot use import outside a module" error.

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it clearer. If you want to use it in the browser you don't need to install it on the server. If you want to use it on the server you will.

Comment: Okay so I went ahead and did what you said but when I try and just do a console.log(sqrt(16)) within the script tag in my HTML I get an error that sqrt is undefined. Additionally, I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "mathjs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." error for the external js file where I use that import statement.

Comment: If you are using mathjs in the html like I posted then you can delete any import statements for mathjs on your server side code. You can also delete the `<script src = 'rootcalc.js'` tag you had in the html too.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I really appreciate you trying to help me with this. I am still a little confused though. If I take out the <script src = 'rootcalc.js' tag how can my HTML file know what the rootCalc() function does since there is no link to my js file? Whenever I hit the submit button on my website it is supposed to call that function but I get an undefined error. Additionally, when you mean server side code is that my javascript code you are refering to?

Comment: Nvm lol I figured out what you were saying and I fixed my errors. Thank you so much for all your help.